# How to unblock a facebook page to use open graph apis

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm using Facebook-sdk (python) to publish posts on a facebook page I manage. Recently I have mistakenly tried to publish too many posts in a short time, so it seems like my page is blocked. Whenever I try to publish a post, I got the following exception:

```
facebook.GraphAPIError: It looks like you were misusing this feature by going too fast. You’ve been blocked from using it.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Just wait and it will go away.

Comment: you are being restricted by facebook, they will lift the restriction after a while, sometimes as long as two weeks.

Comment: There may be an issue in your code that caused this, you would need to post your code by editing the question for help on this